# Como puedo cambiar un separador de comas por tab delimiter

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2013

Tengo un archivo .csv el cual primeramente el cliente me pidió de cambiar las comas separadoras por barras verticales "|"

Ahora me estan pidiendo cambiarlo por tab delimiter pero no logro hacerlo. He buscado varias opciones pero no logro encontrar nada.

Aquí esta el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
string Arch = File.ReadAllText(newFileName); //newFileName es el archivo csv

Arch = Arch.Replace(@",""", @"|""");

File.WriteAllText(newFileName.Substring(0, newFileName.Length - 4) + "_Pipping.csv", Arch);
```

He tratado de remplazar el `@"|""" por @"\t"""` pero la tabulación no resulta. Solo exporta el símbolo \t entre cada columna.

Como ejemplo de texto de entrada y salida.

Texto de entrada:

"nombreDeUsario","NombreCompleto"

Texto de salida:

"NombreDeUsuario"  "NombreCompleto"

Como podria hacer este cambio?

Gracias

Comment: Es un poco cutre, pero el notepad++ te permite hacer un replace con `\t' tal vez te sirva, si quieres te hago una respuesta, con capturas de pantalla

Comment: @rencinas, no puedo usar notepad++ porque esto tengo que hacerlo de forma automatica 4 veces al dia

Comment: pone un texto de ejemplo.. de la entrada y la salida

Comment: @gbianchi, ya actualize mi pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es el `@"\t"` lo cual el prefijo `@` le agrega un slash, lo cual te quedaria `\\t`

usalo directamente sin el prefijo `@`

```
Arch = Arch.Replace(",\"", "\t\"");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El problema esque tengo texto entre las comillas la cual tiene ya comas y si replazo todo, el texto tambien tendra tabulacion entre medio. Es por eso que usaba el prefijo @.
Se necesitaria remplazar las comas que estan entre las comillas

Comment: actualice mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me funciono muy bien